# Hosting ClickOnce in Azure Blob storage and using custom domain

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, clickonce, custom-domain

I am using Clickonce for deploying my WPF application and this is being done in Azure Blob storage. Since this is a custom URL it won't be white listed in many of the client machines and hence I mapped a custom domain for the same. I was able to access the HTML page and download the setup file but download of .application file is not being done as connection could not establish a trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.

Is there a way to overcome this? Can I map SSL certificates to my custom domain.

Answer (score 2):

Taken from the [documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-custom-domain-name):

> Azure Storage does not yet natively support HTTPS with custom domains.
>   You can currently Use Azure CDN to access blobs by using custom
>   domains over HTTPS.

Comment: Is this still the case?